Proof that Dedekind Cuts are isomorphic to decimal expansions?
The real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ are defined as the superset of the $\mathbb{Q}$ with additional elements to yield Dedekind Completeness. Specifically, every subset with an upper bound in $\mathbb{R}$ has a Supremum in $\mathbb{R}$ (or equivalently, every set with a lower bound in $\mathbb{R}$ has an Infimum in $\mathbb{R}$)
Dedekind Cuts are a specific type of subset of the rationals which (a) have upper bounds in $\mathbb{Q}$, and (b) contain every member of $\mathbb{Q}$ that's less than any other element. Such that they can be represented as $(-\infty, r)\cap\mathbb{Q}$. They're used in actually constructing the real numbers.
I've noticed, however, that in some cases, irrational numbers are talked about with approximate decimal expansions. Not often in pure math; but in a few cases, for instance in Cantor's Diagonal Theorem.
Which brings me to the question - how does one prove that the set of Dedekind cuts corresponds bijectively to the set of decimal expansions (with the below exception)?
Now, I'm aware of the quirk where decimals that end in $\overline{9}$ have another decimal form ending in $\overline{0}$ : for instance, $4.1\overline{9}=4.2\overline{0}=4.2$, and I'm equally aware that that will happen in any base.
So to clarify the above, how does one prove that the set of Dedekind cuts corresponds 1-to-1 with the set of decimal expansions that don't end in $\overline{0}$? Or, more generally, to expansions in any base-n that don't end in $\overline{0}$?

Is there more to this than cuts are bijective with reals and reals are bijective with their decimal expansions (with a consistent choice of expansions ending in $\overline{9}$ versus ending in $\overline{0}$)?

This is shown for example in Theorem II.7.11 in Amann-Escher’s Analysis I.

@SarcasticSully wouldn't you need to define addition and multiplication for infinite decimals before? Has anyone done it yet?

You will be able to prove this yourself. Here are the steps. Use the wikipedia definition of the Dedekind cuts.

Start with a decimal extension. Show that it defines a dedekind cut. This proves that you have injection from decimal extensions into cuts.

Now, for the reverse direction. Consider a cut, and consider rationals with $k$ digits after the comma. These admit a max in the cut which we denote with $m_k$. Prove that $m_k$ converges as $k \rightarrow \infty$ to a decimal extension. This proves that you have an injection from cuts into extensions.


And that proves that you have bijection between the two ensembles.
